# Validating whether or not a button was clicked in a panel

Tags: c#, validation, button

So I'm trying to validate whether or not a button is clicked within a panel.  This is to then reserve a seat on that button if there is no one else's name on it.  I keep getting the error 'panel' does not contain a definition for etc..etc.

```
    public void DisplayReservations(String[] seating)
    {
        pnlBox.Controls.Clear();

        int startTop = 10;
        int startLeft = 10;

        for (int seat = 0; seat <= seating.GetUpperBound(0); seat++)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button();
            this.Controls.Add(newButton);
            newButton.Text = ("Seat: " + (seat + 1) + " " + seating[seat]);
            newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(startTop, startLeft + (seat * 30));
            newButton.Click += AButton_Click;
            pnlBox.Controls.Add(newButton);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radDenver_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        piclogo.Load("Cessna.jpg");
        lblFlightInfoOut.Text = "";
        lblStatusOut.Text = "";
        //show the flight info

        lblFlightInfoOut.Text = flight1.FlightInfo();


        string[] seatChart1 = flight1.GetReservationList();

        if (flight1.IsFull() == false)
        {

            DisplayReservations(seatChart1);
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayReservations(seatChart1);
            lblStatusOut.Text = "Flight " + flight2.Plane + " to " + flight1.Destination + " Is Full";
        }
    }

    private void radKC_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        piclogo.Load("Piper.jpg");
        lblStatusOut.Text = "";
        lblFlightInfoOut.Text = "";

        //show the flight info

        lblFlightInfoOut.Text = flight2.FlightInfo();

        string[] seatChart2 = flight2.GetReservationList();

        if (flight2.IsFull() == false)
        {

            DisplayReservations(seatChart2);
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayReservations(seatChart2);
            lblStatusOut.Text = "Flight " + flight2.Plane + " to " + flight2.Destination + " Is Full";
        }


    }

    private void btnNameSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "";
        int seatNum;
        if (CheckText(txtName.Text) == true)
        {
            name = txtName.Text;


            if (radDenver.Checked == true)
            {
                if (ValidSelect(pnlBox.SelectedIndex) == true)
                {
                    seatNum = pnlBox.SelectedIndex;
                    if (flight1.MakeReservation(name, seatNum) == true)
                    {
                        lblStatusOut.Text = "Seat " + (seatNum + 1) + " is now Reserved for " + name;
                        DisplayReservations(flight1.GetReservationList());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblStatusOut.Text = "Sorry " + name + " Seat " + (seatNum + 1) + " is Taken";
                    }
                }

            }
            else if (radKC.Checked == true)
            {
                if (ValidSelect(pnlBox.SelectedIndex) == true)
                {
                    seatNum = pnlBox.SelectedIndex;
                    if (flight2.MakeReservation(name, seatNum) == true)
                    {
                        lblStatusOut.Text = "Seat " + (seatNum + 1) + " is now Reserved for " + name;
                        DisplayReservations(flight2.GetReservationList());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblStatusOut.Text = "Sorry " + name + " Seat " + (seatNum + 1) + " is Taken";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatusOut.Text = "Please Select a destination at Step 1";
            }
        }
    }


    private bool ValidSelect(int SelectedIndex)
    {
        if (pnlBox.AButton_Click == false)
        {
            lblStatusOut.Text = "Please Choose a seat from the List";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What? Where are you getting the error? The actual thing the compiler is looking for and complaining about, which you unhelpfully replaced with "etc..etc." is kind of a key piece as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first post.  it's way down at validSelect method.  the whole error reads 'Panel' does not contain a definition for 'AButton_Click' and no extension method 'AButton_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'Panel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Earlier in the code, you use `AButton_Click` as a handler for a `Click` event. What makes you think the `pnlBox` object should have a member of the same name? What makes you think that member should be able to be treated as a `bool`? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, and explain in precise terms exactly what error message(s) you get, what you've tried to do to fix them, and what specifically you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your code in your function named `DisplayReservations` I noticed that the function `AButton_Click` are set as the fired event when clicking a button inside the panel:

```
newButton.Click += AButton_Click;
```

The reason why you get the error down in the function `ValidSelect` is because of the following line:

```
if (pnlBox.AButton_Click == false)
```

When we use a 'dot', we want to access something inside an object. And as we can see at the top of your code, `AButton_Click` is just another function in your code and not a part of your panel (`pnlBox`). The function `AButton_Click` should be fired like this

```
if (AButton_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty) == false)
```

Normally a button's event function would look like this:

```
private void AButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And then you'll have to enter the sender and the EventArgs when calling the function in the if-statement.

BUT! Even then I believe you've misunderstood something. Are you trying to detect if a button with the function `AButton_Click` as its click event is currently being pressed?

If so, this is not the way. You cannot detect it in that way. You are trying to detect if a button on the panel is being pressed, when pressing the button `btnNameSubmit` as seen in `btnNameSubmit_Click`. That makes little sense if you ask me :D. Furthermore, the return type of `AButton_Click` is probably `void`. So you can't even get a `false` out of the function if calling it. So using it in an if-statement is invalid.

I can give a better solution if you tell me some things I am unsure of:

1. What does the buttons do when pressed? What is the code behind `AButton_Click`?
2. What is the purpose of calling `ValidSelect` in your function `btnNameSubmit_Click`?
3. If you in `ValidSelect` checks if a pnlBox button is being pressed. How can you then press the button `btnNameSubmit`?

I hope my explanations so far is understandable. When I know more I'll edit my answer and add more information.

Comment: I see your point and am changing some things around to see if I can figure it out myself.  Thank you for that outside opinion, it makes more sense than what I was originally trying to do. Chances are I still might need help on it as I am new to this language.

Comment: Worry not. Just ask again if need be. Though, FYI, it's 02:40 AM at my place so I'm probably asleep by then. I'll answer when I wake up then :D